# Proof of a series of congruences

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove that this is impossible:
$$ \begin{cases} a_2  a_1 \equiv a_1 \pmod{n}\\ a_3  a_2 \equiv a_2 \pmod{n} \\ a_4a_3 \equiv a_3 \pmod{n} \\ \ldots\\ a_1a_k \equiv a_k \pmod{n} \end{cases}$$

For any $n>1$, any $k \le\ n$ and any $a_1,a_2,a_3...a_k \le\ n$ without repetitions (if $a_1 = 5$, there can not be another $a$ that has value 5).

Comment: Please don't use $*$ for multiplication. In mathematics, it most commonly denotes *convolution*, and never multiplication. You may use `\cdot` ($\cdot$) for multiplication, but in this case that is hardly needed, so I deleted the asterisks.

Comment: Asterisks aside, can you tell us a bit about what you tried to solve the problem? Any thoughts? Things you attempted that didn't (seem to) work?

Comment: I attempted trying to add or subtract all of them together, getting something like (a2a1)-a1+(a3a2)-a2+(a4a3)-a3+...+(a1ak)-ak = number divisible with n. The idea was if most of the stuff can cancel eachother, in the end I would get a contradiction, but so far no success. It only cancels each other when n=2 and I subtract them because I get (a2a1)-a1-(a1a2)+a2 = number divisible with n, where (a2a1) cancels with (a1a2), and I am left with a2 ≡ a1 (mod n).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another tack you could try: Start with $a_1\equiv a_1a_2$ and substitute $a_2\equiv a_2a_3$ on the right, getting $a_1\equiv a_1a_2a_3$. Do it again with $a_3\equiv a_3a_4$, and so on. Oh, and also notice the nice, cyclical nature of the problem: There is nothing special about $a_1$ or $a_k$ or any of the $a_j$ in between.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $\gcd(a_i, n) \ne 1$  then $\gcd(a_i - 1, n) = 1$ so $a_{i-1}$ is divisible by $n$.